# How to call data datafetch function only after data is completely store in core data in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am getting some data from API which I am storing in core data, and retrieving that data stored in core data and displaying it on collectionview.

Currently i m facing issue like. my data fetching function is getting called before data stored in function completion hence getting 0 records first time.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.fetchExchangeRateData() // API calling + saving data to core data
        self.retrieveExchangeRateData(). // data fetching from core data 
    }


@objc func fetchExchangeRateData() {

        if isConnectedToInternet() == true {
            let webserviceURLNew = webserviceURL + "live?access_key=" + accessToken + "&format=1"
            
            Webservice.shared.getExchangeRateData(with: webserviceURLNew) { (exchangeRateData, error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                guard let exchangeRateData = exchangeRateData else {return}
                self.exchangeRateData = exchangeRateData
                CoreManager.shared.saveExchangeRateData(exchangeRate: self.exchangeRateViewModel!.exchangeRate)
            }
        } else {
            showAlert(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Please check your internet connection")
        }
    }
```

Please suggest the way yo handle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write  this function with completion handler

```
@objc func fetchExchangeRateData(completion:  @escaping (Bool)->Void) {

        if isConnectedToInternet() == true {
            let webserviceURLNew = webserviceURL + "live?access_key=" + accessToken + "&format=1"
            
            Webservice.shared.getExchangeRateData(with: webserviceURLNew) { (exchangeRateData, error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    completion(false)
                    return
                }
                guard let exchangeRateData = exchangeRateData else {return}
                self.exchangeRateData = exchangeRateData
                CoreManager.shared.saveExchangeRateData(exchangeRate: self.exchangeRateViewModel!.exchangeRate)
                completion(true)
            }
        } else {
            completion(false)
            showAlert(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Please check your internet connection")
        }
    }
```

Use it like this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.fetchExchangeRateData {[weak self] (success) in

           if success {
              self?.retrieveExchangeRateData()
            }
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: but what if internet is not there how this method will get called?

Comment: you will get it in success .... if internet not available you will get false in schusses... you can act accordingly